# google sheets use named range inside custom function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have defined a custom function like below. I want to use a named range in it but I keep getting the error that the named range is not defined. I tried to use **INDIRECT** function, but INDIRECT is also not recognized.

```
function RetentionCalculatorV1(x) {
  return x* INDIRECT("V1.RetentionRateFrom1MonthAgo");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spreadsheets functions are not available in Google Apps Script.

Try

```js
return x* SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRangeByName("V1.RetentionRateFrom1MonthAgo").getValue();
```